# Ho to create a PR from Gittyup?

Tags: github, gitlab

I am used to use github-desktop and it has an option to create a PR inside it. And I wonder if it is possible to do so from Gittyup too.

I've explored the menu bar but I seems to not be able to see where I can do so.

Comment: The answer appears to be "no". This should not be tagged both github and gitlab as they have different systems; GitLab call theirs "merge requests", not "pull requests".

Comment: @torek, you're right - it's not implemented yet, per https://github.com/Murmele/Gittyup/discussions/385#discussioncomment-4311495